# wordpress the_content() is not shown in proper div

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show, in the registered widget area, some category post with this piece of code:

```
function category_post_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title'    => '',
        'link'     => '',
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts, 'category_post' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => '2', 'post_type' => 'post')
    );
    $list = '<article class="format-standard" id="post-70">';

    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        //get the ID of your post in the loop
        $id = get_the_ID();

        $post_excerpt = get_post_meta($id, 'post_excerpt', true);  
        $post_thumbnail= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
        $list .= '

            <div class="single_cate_post floatleft">
            '.$post_thumbnail.'
            <h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3> 
            '.the_content().' //the content is not shown after h3 tag.
            <a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="readmore">Read More</a>
            </div>

        ';
    endwhile;
    $list.= ' </article>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('category_post', 'category_post_shortcode');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

It supposed to show the post text `the_content()` after `<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>`. However, the text of the post goes all the way up to the post thumbnail image. Please have a look here: [image of the problem](http://postimg.org/image/mev7i4i4x/). (The format of this image is not supported for embedding in a SO question.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are appending strings to `$list`, `get_content()` echoes the content immediately. That's why you should use `get_the_content()` at this point.

> You may use get_the_content() to return the content value instead of outputting it directly.

**-- the WordPress Codex**

Adding a simple "the" will fix your problem:

```
$list .= get_the_content();
```